# Can semantic segmentation detect objects with very close pixel intensities with the background

Tags: python, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am currently working on a computer vision project for detecting inhomogeneities in Light patterns. I have a sample data [image: here] to explain the concept, which basically aims to detect blind spots in a light pattern, where the difference in pixel values between the blind spots and the background is very small (this is captured in the sample image data by using a different shade of gray for the small rectangle some in the middle).
I would like to know if semantic segmentation does well in these cases and what other possible solutions can be applied to such problem.

Comment: you _might_ be able to train a network to tolerate such data, but why? just fix whatever causes this low contrast in the first place.

Comment: T@ChristophRackwitz , the data  depicts the inhomogeneities that exists in light patterns of the actual data, made possible due to varying pixel intensity values and that is how the real data is. Although this sample data  might be a bit extreme in terms of differences in intensity values but the actual data has similar differences.

Comment: 1 - measure illumination unevenness. 2 -  correct for the unevenness. There is no training or ML involved in this problem at all.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. Perhaps a little more clarification from me. The goal is to detect(not measure) regions in image data  where there is illumination unevenness in some lightening devices, this regions represents a defect(e.g poorly powered or faulty LED/unit) in the device whose image is being analyzed.

Comment: And how do you plan to present the output? As a set of coordinates where illumination is different from elsewhere? As a heat map? As an outline plot? Just a yes/no quality check?

Comment: A yes/no and a localization of the unevenness region(say in a heat map like form), which would aid easy identification of failed light source units within the device.